# Unsubscribe or Remove user from Mailgun mailing list using Curl and PHP

Tags: php, mailgun

I've got my subscribe code working fine, but my unsubscribe method is not. When a user closes his account in my software, I want to remove him from any Mailgun mailing lists he might be on.

Here's what I have that's not working:

```
    $data = ["subscribed"=>False, 'address'=>$user->email, 'name'=>$user->name];
    $api_key = env('MAILGUN_SECRET');
    $listname = "mylist@mydomain.com";

    $options=['--user'=>'api:'.$api_key];
    $url = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/lists/$listname/members";

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "api:".$api_key);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    // Store the data:
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```

When I then query the list, the current user is still showing as subscribed. I have tried:

```
    "subscribed"=>"no"
    "subscribed"=>"False"
    $url = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/lists/$listname/members/$user->email"; 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
```

but none of these adjustments have unsubbed (or removed) the user. Can anyone please show me what I'm doing wrong?
TIA!

Update: I did manage to DELETE a user by specifying all three:

```
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

and

```
    "subscribed"=>"no"
```

but I'd also like to unsubscribe people without deleting. :)

Comment: I'm looking at the mailing lists doc and from that I would suggest: include the member email address in the url like you tried, and set the `customrequest` to "PUT" and only include the `subscribed` param in `$data`

Comment: Thanks much for the suggestion. It worked!! /happydance Thank you again! :D

Comment: np, happy mailgunning